# Como restringir acesso à rotas em angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, auth

Como faço para restringir acesso em algumas rotas, e permite que usuários logados possam acessar seu conteúdo em Angulajs.

Answer (score 8):

Para validação de usuário você poderia implementar o evento [$routeChangeStart](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route), que é disparado sempre que uma rota é acionada, assim você pode validar o usuário e redirecioná-lo para outra rota caso não esteja autorizado.

Segue um exemplo de código:

```
var app = angular.module("Test", []).
//Simple Routes
    config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/restricted",{ templateUrl: "index.html" })
            .when("/login", { templateUrl: "login.html", controller: "LoginCtrl" })
            .otherwise( { redirectTo: "/login" });
    })
  .run(function($rootScope, $location, accessControl) {
        $rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {

            //Checking the accessControl service
            if(!accessControl.canAccess(next)){
                //if can´t access the future route we can redirect him to the login page
                $location.path("/login");
            }
        }
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

se estiver utilizando o ui.router, você pode utilizar o evento,

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState){
   if(regra) //Sua regra aqui.
      event.preventDefault(); // Utilizando esse método você PARA o ciclo natural, ou seja não vai mais executar a chamada da rota, assim você pode fazer seu tratamento.
});
```

o mesmo vale para o evento  `$routeChangeStart`,

Edit: Alterações para mostrar de acordo com os comentários.

```
.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){

            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState){
               if(!$rootScope.logado) //a variavel logado está false.
                  event.preventDefault(); // quando falar, preventDefault, não vai mudar a rota, e continuar no msm 'current' que você se encontra
            });
    }]);
```

Comment: e como funciona a regra!?

Comment: pode ser uma variavel global?  do tipo $rootScope.logado?

Comment: @EltonTomasLaice isso vai de acordo com sua regra de negócio, por exemplo if(user.PodeAcessar), é uma validação como quiser. e para utilizar o $rootScope, basta voce injetar o mesmo no controller onde aplicar o evento .$on, eu custumo utilizar no modulo principal na função .run()

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @EltonTomasLaice deu certo ? era isso que você precisava ?